# XSLT copy data without specified character

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML:

```
<Data>
    <Product date1="2015-01-01" date2="">
    </Product>
</Data>
```

I want to copy the value of the `date1` into the `date2` without the hyphen (-) character. The result should be:

```
<Data>
    <Product date1="2015-01-01" date2="20150101">
    </Product>
</Data>
```

Could anyone give me an example how to do this with **XSLT**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the translate() function, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@date1, '-', '')"/>
```

No context, because no context was given.

Comment: It might be worth adding how to use `<xsl:attribute>` to get this into `@date2`.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig You are assuming it's necessary to use `<xsl:attribute>` here; I am not .

Comment: Not really necessary, no. I am assuming it would be more robust to write code that copies all attributes from the original (including future ones) and more maintainable not to hard-code the element name. I also assume that the simplest way I know of how to do that is using `<xsl:attribute>`.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig You could match on `Product` and use AVT for `@date2`. It really depends on what else goes on here.